# Problem after updating Galaxy S3 to Android 4.1.1

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-3, music-player

After updating my Galaxy S3 to Android 4.1.1, I started to experience some problems.

For instance, while listening music or 'surfing' in the phone, suddenly phone starts to 'nearly' freeze for a 1 second and turns to normal life.

If I am listening to music, naturally music stops for 1 second and then continues. I do not know if this is a performance issue, or another thing.

Can someone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Most probably it looks like a OS issue, might be firmware related, might be kernel related. Have you tried a factory reset? Or sometimes even a reboot might clear things up. If 4.1 is not working well for you, you can always downgrade by flashing an older firmware via ODIN. Get you firmwares from http://samfirmware.com. You will need to register in order to download files from there.